# How to keep the original shape when simulating cloth?

Tags: cloth-simulation

this is the original shape
[image: before]

after simulation

[image: after simulation]

I want the skirt keep the shape rather than dropping down like this
[image: Lolita skirt]

Maybe it can be solve by Cloth Stiffness Scaling option but I really don'n know how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing Bending and Structural. To have an order of magnitude, you can check the Presets :

- Silk : Bending 0.05 ; Structural 5.00
- Rubber : Bending 25.00 ; Structural 15.00

Stiffness Scaling allows to control the stiffness of specific parts of the mesh. Create two vertex group (one for Struct, one for Bending), assign all your vertices to both groups, them weight-paint them.

- Blue vertices will have the stiffness defined in Overall stiffness
- Red vertices will have a stiffness of Overall + Max

Comment: I try your method but not obviously,maybe my other option is not right.But I found another easy way is assigned the vertex group as pin in cloth-simulation.

Answer (score 0):

I try to assign the vertex group like this
[image]

And select the vertex group in pinning.It can also work greatly in animation.